# Unable to open or uninstall Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded visual studio code a while ago but was never able to open it. When I open the app, I get the error "unable to write program user data". When I run as administrator, a window opens briefly before closing again. When I try to uninstall the program, I get error 5, "unable to create a temporary file. Setup aborted."

I have tried to create new TEMP and TMP directories but it made no difference.

This is on windows 11, the x64 bit version of vscode.

I have installed and used the same version of Visual Studio Code on a previous device (with windows 10 however) and never had any issues.

Comment: You should [edit] to explicitly say what platform you're on (presumably windows), how exactly you installed it, and any relevant version information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to write data.
It means you do not have the necessary permissions for the directories. I see you tried already to run as ADM.

Try to check if your user account got the necessary permissions to write in the directories that you want. In the error message, maybe it shows the directory in question, if not, try first the VSC directories or the PROJECT directory. See below:

To do this, navigate to the directories specified (Or project directory) in the error message and right-click on them. Select "Properties" and then go to the "Security" tab. Make sure that your user account is listed and has the "Full control" permission.

You can also try to reset the settings for VSCode, by running the command `Code --reset-settings` in the command prompt.